# how to update dynamically href attribute using htmx

Tags: javascript, html, htmx

I have the next "pseudo-template" code that uses htmx:

```html
<main hx-boost="true">

    <section id="products-container-id">
        {{foreach $product = $products}}
            {{render "components/CardProduct" $product}}
        {{end}}
    </section>

    <a href="/products?page=2" id="more-products-btn-id" hx-target="#products-container-id" hx-swap="beforeend">
        More products</a>

    <script defer>
        (() => {
            let productBtn = document.querySelector("#more-products-btn-id")

            let productsContainer = document.querySelector("#products-container-id")

            productBtn.addEventListener("htmx:afterSettle", (e) => {

                let currentPage = Number(new URLSearchParams(productBtn.href).get("page"))

                if (!isNaN(currentPage))
                    productBtn.setAttribute("href", "?page=" + (currentPage + 1))
            })
        })()
    </script>
</main>
```

The idea is when the user visits for the first time the website, he sees, let's say 10 products and then if he presses the "More products" button htmx loads 10 more products that comes from the server and put it inside of the `products-container-id` element and then after the DOM gets updated the href attribute of the `more-products-id` element is updated to the page param plus 1.

The problem is that when I trigger the "More products" button the href attribute is succesfully updated but the request after it, always visits "/?page=2" and never triggers a request different than that URL.

As always sorry for my english, I hope that all of the problem gets understanded and if you can help me I will appreciate it

Comment: Where is the code that loads 10 more products? Is it creating a duplicate "More products" button?

Comment: @Barmar it doesn't concerns to the problem, the point is that htmx always visits "/products?page=2" and doesn't visit "/products?page=3" or "/products?page=4" and so on. Also I have a typo in the href sorry bout that

Comment: @Barmar it loads 10 `div`'s it doesn't render any button again

Comment: Try to put the event listener on the `<section>`.

Comment: I'm not familiar with HTMX, maybe it requires you to change the href differently.

Answer (score 0):

I think the link tag should replace too.
Can you try

`hx-swap="outerHTML"`

reference: https://htmx.org/examples/click-to-load/#demo